# How to stop threads when press Ctrl-C in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, exit-code

I want to stop threads when accept `Ctrl-C`, so according to some documents, I tried:

```
try:
    threads = [t.join(10) for t in threads if t is not None and t.isAlive()]
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Ctrl-c received! Sending kill to threads..."
    for t in threads:
        t.kill_receives = True

    # some other process
```

but I find this also means `threads will stop after 10 seconds`, this can not meet my requirements. So I remove `10` from code:

```
try:
    threads = [t.join() for t in threads if t is not None and t.isAlive()]
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Ctrl-c received! Sending kill to threads..."
    for t in threads:
        t.kill_receives = True

    # some other process
```

then I can not kill the program with `Ctrl-C`.

So how can I kill all threads elegant?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python